# Normal Map from UV Map

Tags: uv, normal-map

Good afternoon to all, I have a quite simple question.
I unwrapped a model, a building wall, and I exported the UV Layer to GIMP. Then I mapped the layer to fit the textures in it and refreshed the resulted texture in Blender.

I've been using Normal maps and other detail maps for my other textures. 
Will programs such as CrazyBump create a valid normal map for me?
Won't I see any sharp borders or similar in the uv map?

I ask this question because I've never exported UV layers; I've always used the classic rectangle texture and applied it directly in Blender together with the normal map.